# Choosing black sock probability

Tags: probability

My sock drawer has the following socks: 3 green, 5 white, and 7 black. I hurriedly pack for a trip one dark morning, randomly grabbing 5 socks from the drawer and putting them in the suitcase. What is the probability that I will have at least one pair of black socks?

Looking at this problem from a novice point of view, I thought that this would be simply $100\%$ minus the probability of choosing a set with no black socks. This, however, isn't the correct answer because the problem states the word 'pairs' which most likely affected the result.

How does this change my approach? What type of approach would you use instead "negating" the probability.

Comment: You just need to include the sets with exactly one black sock, too. The negation of "has at least one pair of black socks" is "has zero or one black sock".

Comment: Off topic: Man, odd counts of *all* colors?  And you pack exactly 5 socks (in the dark) for a trip?  :D

Comment: @Wildcard, It can happen if you arr a pirate.

Answer (score 1):

Number of black socks $X$ grabbed from the drawer follows a [Hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) distribution with parameters $N=15$ (all socks, $K=7$ (black socks), and $n=5$ (number of socks you grab).

What you want is at least two black socks, which is $P(X\ge 2)=1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)$

which can be calculated numerically using the hypergeometric probability formula.

$P(X=0)=\frac{{8\choose 5} {7\choose 0}}{15\choose 5}$

which is 5 socks chosen out of 8 non-black and 0 chosen out of 7 black

$P(X=1)=\frac{{8\choose 4} {7\choose 1}}{15\choose 5}$

which is 4 socks chosen out of 8 non-black and 1 chosen out of 7 black

Plug in the first formula and get the result.

Answer (score 0):

The total number of choices that you could have made is $\binom{3+5+7}{5}=3003$.

The number of choices containing $\color\red1$ black sock is $\binom{7}{\color\red1}\cdot\binom{3+5}{5-\color\red1}=490$.

The number of choices containing $\color\red0$ black socks is $\binom{7}{\color\red0}\cdot\binom{3+5}{5-\color\red0}=56$.

The probability that you took at least $2$ black socks is therefore:

$$1-\frac{490+56}{3003}=\frac{9}{11}$$

Comment: you calculated the complement of the probability you wanted.

Comment: @Momo: Yep, thanks :)